# .gs/.html - Google Apps Script as a Web App using Form Elements, Html Service and a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently trying to learn some 'Google Apps Script' basics from the 'Web Application' angle.  I want to use the 'HTML Service' because the older 'UI Service' is now depreciated.

Basically what I want to accomplish is to type a name into the 'name' text input and then click the 'Submit' button which should then populate the spreadsheet with the entered value.  I think the code below is close to what I need but I'm not sure how to tie it all together so the form elements work with the .gs code.

Currently the code I posted writes a value in the proper place in the spreadsheet when it is opened.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
index.html

```
<div>
    <? var submit = insertInSS(); ?>
    <p>Add a Name:</p>

    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit"  name="submit"  value="Submit">

    <hr>
    <? var data = getData(); ?>

    <table>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
      <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
      <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
      </tr>
      <? } ?>
    </table>

</div>
```

My code.gs looks like the following

```
  var submissioSSKey = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwkyz';
    function doGet() {
      return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('index')
        .evaluate()
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    }

function getData() {
return SpreadsheetApp
  .openById(submissioSSKey)
  .getActiveSheet()
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues(); 
}

    function insertInSS(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissioSSKey);
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
      var cell = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1,1);
      cell.setValue("name");
    }
```

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a  SUBMIT button works together with a FORM.  You don't have the SUBMIT button in a form.  Note the `onsubmit` event listener in the first FORM tag.  You don't need to configure the trigger to run a script this way, there are other ways.

### Form and Button HTML

```
<div id="inputDiv">
  <form id="inputForm" onsubmit="fncWriteInputData()">
    <label>Some Label Text Here:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" tabindex="1" id="idFirstInput" class="inptFld" placeholder="Msg To User Here" required><br />
    <label>Label Two Here:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" tabindex="2" id="idInputTwo" class="inptFldSgn" required><br />
    <input type="submit" tabindex="3" id="btnSubmitInput" value="Click To Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

### HTML Script Tag

```
<script>
  window.fncWriteInputData=function(){
    console.log("fncWriteInputData ran");
    google.script.run
    .fncRunAppScript(); //Runs server side .gs function

</script>
```

### Code.gs

```
function fncRunAppScript() {
  Code here . . . 
  return someValue;
};
```

This is some basic structure.  You will need to modify and correct it for your needs.

Comment: Sandy, thank-you for trying to help me out.  Your code samples look great but I am not finding the way to success.  I have tried the script tag putting it both in the index.html head and after the body.  I tried to simplify it to just bring up an alert box when the button is clicked but that doesn't work either.  When the button is clicked the page just goes blank.

Comment: Try changing IFRAME in `.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)` to NATIVE.  `.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)`

Comment: Sandy, I found my error; now I am able to write data to the spreadsheet when in IFRAME mode... I was missing a bracket. When I click my f5 key the blank page refreshes and I see the new data entry. When I change it to 'native' it doesn't write to the spreadsheet.  Looking for a 'refresh' cmd for the .gs and also how to grab the text I type in the textbox to pop in the spreadsheet.  So close now...

Comment: Thanks for posting that you found an error.  If you narrow the problem down, and still have trouble, post another question.